# Schematron/Xslt compiler/parser in .Net

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, schematron

I have made a schema compiler that builds an object model in primary memory that encapsulate the schema objects (element, attribute, choice, sequence, ...) using Microsoft System.Xml.Schema in .Net.

I now would like to complement the compiler with a schematron compiler. I have schematron files in both xslt (xsl:stylesheet) and schematron (schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
schemaVersion="iso"). These files have references to some code lists (gc:CodeList). I want to get all the validation information from these files into my object model by compiling/parsing the schematron.

I have started to look at Saxon-HE. But it seems to be useful for xml validation only. Can Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE maybe do the work?

Any suggestions of a schematron environment to choose to help me in this work is appreciated.
Any sample code would also be very helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid StackOverflow isn't a particularly good place for asking about application design and technology choices. Questions tend to be quickly closed as "too broad". The reason is easy to see: I would want to spend a couple of hours examining the requirement before suggesting a preferred way forward.

Comment: I understand. I'm just interested in experiences of doing a similar thing that might be out there. I'm currently working on that investigation myself but Schematron seems to be "a creature that has been living in the shadows for many years and hard to catch". On the other hand Schematron as technology isn't that broad. There might not even exist an Schematron environment that can help me. That makes it an even more narrow question.